# How to fix unreadable content error with Open XML SDK 2.0 excel using SpreadsheetWorker?

Tags: excel, c#-3.0, openxml-sdk

**[SOLVED (see answer below)]** I am using SpreadsheetWorker API to make working with Open XML SDK 2.0 easier. I have an excel spreadsheet that I use as a template when I generate new excel spreadsheets through SpreadsheetWorker. I am getting a "found unreadable content" error when I open my generated files, and excel will correct the problems with the file if you allow it. This is not suitable for production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved my own question:** In my excel spreadsheet that I used as a template, I had some blank cells with 'Hyperlink' styles applied to them. Setting the style of these cells to 'Normal' fixed the problem, and I no longer get the "unreadable content" error when I open generated spreadsheets for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

While adding hyperlinks to excel cell, try to avoid dynamic URL to screenTip attribute. Excel cell takes only 256 charecter long for tooltip. The repaired excel file chops off the characters after this limit.

For Spreadsheet gear,

```
worksheet.Hyperlinks.Add(worksheet.Cells[startRow, startColumn], href, null, "Click here to see details","textToDisplay");
```